# JavaScript and eventhandling

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, onchange

I have been reading a lot on the order in which events are handled in JavaScript. All articles I have read are about bubbling and capturing. That's all about the same kind of event being bubbled/captured from children to parents or from parent to children. You can't really predict in which order these events will be executed. That stuff is really clear.

My question is about the order of events in the following case:
Suppose a screen with a textfield with an onChange listener on it. Next to the field there's a button with an onClick listener on it.
Suppose you alter the textfield's value and keep the cursor in the field and directly press the button.

In all my testing it was always the onChange being executed before the onClick. I have reason to believe that this order is not always the same. 
Does this sound familiar to you?
What can be said about the order in which these onChange and onClick events are handled? Does this also depend on the js implementation, or other factors?

Kind regards,
Guus

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask.

Comment: I believe the change event which triggers onblur should always trigger before the click event

Comment: I believe so too. Do you know if there's any documentation confirming or denying this?